# Creating seperate .js file for d3.js pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am new in d3.js language and try to make a simple pie chart. But I am stuck with a little problem.

This a link of my pie chart [here](http://jsbin.com/zocewinoye/2/edit?html,output)

**Problem**: I want to save this code in rt.js file separately and then i want to link that file with my HTML page. All is done except that i don't know why the linked rt.js file is not showing pie chart.

Can you suggest me what should I need to do?

Comment: are you getting any areas? are you loading the d3.js before your rt.js?

Comment: @bencripps yes I load d3.js before rt.js but pie chart still not showing.

Comment: Can you paste code about how are you linking both d3.js library and your rt.js in your HTML?

Comment: sure @AlexEpelde ` <html><head><script type="text/javascript" src="d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>;</head><body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/rt.js"></script>; </body>`

Comment: You don't need those semicolons after </script>. Is your rt.js file under a lib folder? Are you sure the problem is that your HTML file doesn't load the rt.js file? Put: alert('Hi'); in your file's first line to make sure it's reached.